# homotopy MC element

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, homological-algebra

A homotopy MC element is the Linfty analog of a Maurer-Cartan
element for a Lie algebra. Where is anything written about 
homotopy MC elements as perturbations of strict MC elements?